# Get the height of an item inside last container

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be pretty simple but I can't make it work. I need the height of an item that is inside the last item with a class.

HTML like so:

```
    <div class="tag" >
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="left" id="I need this height !"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

JavaScript poor attempt:

```
lastLeftHeight = $('.tag').last().$('.left').height();
```

I know that doesn't work. It's just to show what I'm trying to get `.tag` items can vary so I can't target a number or an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost had it, but instead of using jquery methods, it can be accomplished with the proper query selector

`$(.tag:last .left).height()`

this will grab the last `.tag` element and find every child element with the class `.left` and return their heights

heres a fiddle demonstrating the selector in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/6e0s4jzj/

Comment: [According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), "*Because `:last` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:last` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:last` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use [`.filter(":last")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)*".

Answer (score 2):

try this ..

```
lastLeftHeight=$('.tag:last > .left').height();
```

Comment: [According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), "*Because `:last` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:last` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:last` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use [`.filter(":last")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)*".

Answer (score 0):

I would try some combination of using children(), filter(), and last() to get the height of a particular child div.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_filtering.asp

This explains a little more about traversing up and down the DOM using jQuery, and with examples that I would think would help.